# jquery-ui droppable hide until mouseover

Tags: jquery-ui, draggable, droppable

Basically I have a container with a droppable inside it. I want the droppable hidden until I drag over the container. I can make this work if the z-index of the droppable is less than the container, but then you can't see where the draggable is since it's hidden behind the container.

Here's a jsbin of the problem: http://jsbin.com/zizipe/3/edit?html,css,js,output

How can I get the droppable to display and still have the draggable show on top of the container?

Answer (score 0):

Not *exactly* what I was trying to do, but I was able to achieve my result by checking the proximity to the droppable. jsbin here: http://jsbin.com/venoz/2/edit?css,js,console,output